# regular expression with group to a string including ( ) and dash

Tags: python

I am trying to use regular expression to find number. But I never succeed. Can anyone help me with it?

```
import re
item='800-850(0.2)'
find_list=re.findall(r'(\d+)\-(\d+)\((\d+)\)$',item)
print(find_list)
[]
```

The above return empty [], what I wanted is [800,850,0.2]. I am using () to capture group.  do I use ( and ) to indicate ( or ) ? and use - to indicate -

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to accept the dot (`.`) for the last number, which is not included by `\d` (equivalent to `[0-9]`).

```py
re.findall(r'(\d+)-(\d+)\(([\d.]+)\)$',item)
```

To make sure the dot is between two consecutive groups of digits, use `(\d+\.\d+)`.

Comment: Thank you so much Unmitigated. it works. it return find_lis t[('800', '850', '0.2')]. why it return a list with single element of a tuple with 3 strings? Can I just return a list with 3 numbers, like this [800,850,0.2]? Thanks

Comment: @roudan Just get the first element, `[*re.findall(r'(\d+)-(\d+)\((\d+\.\d+)\)$',item)[0]]`

Comment: Thanks, then why it return string instead of number inside the list? i.e. above return ['800', '850', '0.2'], can I return [800, 850, 0.2]?

Comment: Your pattern defines 3 groups, so the match has to be 3-item tuple.  You use `findall`, which returns a list of matches.  Hence this particular return value.

Comment: @roudan You can use `float` to convert each element: `[*map(float, re.findall(r'(\d+)-(\d+)\((\d+\.\d+)\)$',item)[0])]`